# Ambiguity of Quotient Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Abstract algebra's "equality vs. isomorphism" problem rears its confusing head once again.

I was thinking about the identity $(G \times H)/H \cong G$. It's pretty easy to justify by stating that $H \cong \{ (e_G, h) \mid h \in H \}$, which is a subgroup of $G$, and when it is quotient-ed out, it's easy to see we get $G$ (or rather, something isomorphic to $G$).

But strictly speaking, $H$ is not a subgroup of $G \times H$. It may be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G \times H$, but there may be more than one. Does it matter which one we pick? In other words, if $H_1, H_2 \trianglelefteq G$ and $H_1 \cong H_2$, is it necessarily true that $G/H_1 \cong G/H_2$?

I can't pin down a counter-example, but I've found a (admittedly, simple) criterion for isomorphism: if there is an automorphism $\alpha : G \to G$ such that $\alpha(H) = K$, then $G/H \cong G/K$. (So, a counter-example would have $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic, but in a way that's "outside" $G$.) This is sufficient, but is it also necessary?

Comment: Second line: "Identity"?? Weird name for an isomorphism...

Comment: A very simple counterexample is $\mathbb Z$ and its subgroups.

Comment: @DonAntonio I find myself referring to short statements like that as identities. Probably a holdover from "trig identities". Is that incorrect or just non-standard?

Comment: @Tunococ That's a really clean counter-example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counter example:
let $G=S_3\times Z_3$ , $H=A_3\times1$ and $K=1\times Z_3$

then you can easily say that $H$ and $K$ isomorphic subgroup of $G$.

But $G/H\cong Z_2\times Z_3$ and $G/K\cong S_3$ so they are not isomorphic.

For infinite groups, it is more interesting indeed.

Let $G=\mathbb Z$ and $H=2\mathbb Z$ then $G\cong H$ which means this group isomorphic to its proper subgroup. And $G/H$ is nontrivial group so certanly isomorphism is different from equality.

Comment: @Henry:I was thinking whether  its converse is true or not, I mean if $G/H\cong G/K$ then $H\cong K$ ? I noticed that it is also wrong.

Comment: would you mind providing a counterexample? I can't figure out one...

Comment: @Vim : I had answered this question last year. Probably, I had an example at that time but now I need to think.

Comment: Alright. I'll also ponder on it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Vim: Let $G=S_3\times Q_8$ and $H=A_3\times Q_8$ and $K=S_3\times <i>$. Then $G/H=G/K=Z_2$ but $H,K$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: what does $Q_8$ stand for...?

Comment: The Quaternion group of order $8$. $Q_8=\{1,-1,i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}$

Comment: Nice example. Thanks

Comment: @Vim: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Even smaller finite counterexample: $G=C_4 \times C_2$, $H=C_2 \times \{1\}$ and $K=\{1\} \times C_2$. Then $G/H \cong V_4$, Klein's Viergruppe and $G/K \cong C_4$ a cyclic group of order 4.