# Why is so important "to count" the number of the (all isomorphic to each other) Sylow $p$-subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

"*[...] From the standpoint of group theory, isomorphic groups have the same properties and need not be distinguished [...]*" (from [Group isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism) wiki page). Why is then so important to get information (by Sylow III) on the cardinality $n_p$ of $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$, whose elements are all isomorphic to each other?

---

I Just found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1471483/615081) similar post, which reinforces what in the answers/comments of this.

Comment: Are you sure that $n_p$ does not count the distinct Sylow-p-subgroups ?

Comment: For the structure of finite groups all parts of the Sylow theorems are "so important". The questions coming up here at this site demonstrate this.

Comment: I don't think this question has a good answer. Sometimes isomorphic groups can be considered "the same", sometimes not (for example, when we are counting subgroups of a group for various reasons). It all depends on context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just useful.

For example, say you want to understand how groups of order $30$ look. That is, you want to create a list of all isomorphism types of groups of order $30$. Lets work this out using Sylow's theorem and semi-direct products, it is a fun exercise!

We know that $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$. Then $n_3 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $n_3\mid 30$ gives you that $n_3$ could be $1$ or $10$. Similarly $n_5$ could be $1$ or $6$.

If $n_3=10$, i.e. there are $10$ distinct $p$-sylow groups, each have $2$ elements which are not the identity, we get that there are $20$ elements of order $3$. Similarly, if $n_5=6$ we get that there are $24$ elements of order $5$. Hence, if both hold together there must be at least $44$ elements in the group, which is impossible for a group of size $30$, so this possibility is excluded.

Hence, it must hold that either $n_3=1$ or $n_5=1$. Hence, if $P$ is a $3$-group and $Q$ is a $5$-group then at least one of them is normal (recall that a $p$-group is normal iff $n_p=1$, as all $p$-Sylow groups are conjugate). This implies that $R=PQ$ is also a subgroup, also $|PQ|=15$ so it has index $2$ and it is therefore normal as well.

If $K$ is *any* $2$-group it follows that $K\cap PQ$ is trivial (as $PQ$ has no elements of order $2$) and $G=RK$.

This tells us a lot about the structure, but in order to explicate that we need to use [semidirect products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product). Semidirect products tell us that the group $G$ is determined by an action of a group of order $2$ on a group of order $15$. The only group of order $2$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and it is easy to prove along similar lines to what we did above that the only group of order $15$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ (I highly recommend that you work out the entire case for groups of order $pq$ for $p$ and $q$ prime).

So what such group actions could exist? Recall that an action of $G$ on $H$ is simply a homomorphism from $G$ to $Aut H$. It is easy to prove that $Aut\mathbb{Z}_{15} = \mathbb{Z}_{15}^\times \simeq \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ (it is of order $8$ because $\varphi(15) = 8$ and direct calculation shows that there is an element of order $4$ but no elements of order $8$).

So the question boils down to, how many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Any such automorphism is completely determined by the image of the non trivial element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which has to map to an element of order $1$ (in this case we get the trivial homomorphism) or $2$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ has three elements of order $2$ there are four such homomorphisms, and we have proved that there are at most $4$ non-isomorphic groups of order $30$!

Note that we can't say that there are exactly $4$ such groups, because different homomorphisms can give rise to isomorphic groups. We haven't discussed how to "translate" such homomorphisms to groups, but this really isn't necessary here.

Why? Because we already know of four non isomorphic groups of order $30$: $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times D_6$, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times D_{10}$ and $D_{30}$. The above proves that *any* group of order $30$ *must* be isomorphic to one of these groups.

Pretty neat, huh?

Comment: Yep, definitely. But then, in spite of the reported excerpt of the wiki page, I'd say that mutually isomorphic (sub)groups conveniently *needs* to be distinguished sometime.

Comment: There are various notions of isomorphism in different branches of mathematics: homeomorphism, diffeomorphism, isometry etc. etc. When we have one we can "identify" the objects.  But there can still be different guises that they come in, and situations where we wish to distinguish those.  We are generalizing here (mathematicians favorite activity).  Explore the different topics to find specific examples.

Comment: Well, they *are* distinguished. No one said that they are the same, only that they have the same structure. This is relevant because we consider them as a subgroup of a particular group, so each is a different subset.
When given groups in the abstract, though, they are indistinguishable from the point of view of group theory as there is no property which can be stated in terms of group theory which distinguishes them. There could be other underlying structure which does though.

Comment: Would it be correct stating that Sylow $p$-subgroup is one (up to isomorphism)?

Comment: Technically correct but very misleading. *all* groups of order $p$ are isomorphic, and this is true regardless to the fact that the groups you considered came up as $p$-Sylow subgroups of a particular group. On the other hand, while the $p$-Sylow groups are isomorphic (which is trivial), they are *different subsets* of the group. So in a very strong sense, they are *not* the same.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you see isomorphic groups as the same or not does rely heavily on the use case. For example you may identify the free abelian group on one generator with your favourite representation of the integers $\mathbb Z$ via the caconical isomorphism.

You don‘t want to turn all isomorphisms into identities though. In the case of Sylow-subgroups the fact that they are isomorphic gives you a well defined relation between them, but it is essential to view them as distinct subsets of the group, as they can be used (I think) to distinguish finite groups from each other...

Answer (score 1):

From Sylow-II, you know that a p-Sylow subgroup of a finite group G is normal if and only if it is unique. If you find out that a certain p-Sylow is unique, you know that it is normal in G (it is a characteristic subgroup, since it is the only subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to itself). Having a normal subgroup almost always allows you to express G as a semidirect product of its subgroups, helping you to classify it.

Comment: I'm aware that $n_p$ really bears important information, but my doubt was on the "[...] need not be distinguished [...]" of the popular wiki page that I've linked.

Comment: I think that the wiki page was referring to isomorphic groups if you take them as independent entities. For example, if you have $C_5 \times C_4$, you can say that it is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $20$, $C_{20}$. So, there is no need to distinguish them if, for example, you want to classify the groups of order 20. On the other hand, if you want to take a look at the $2$-Sylow subgroups of $S_4$, they are all isomorphic to $D_4$, but you cannot take them as independent objects, as they are identified by the permutations that generate them within $S_4$.

Comment: I hope that my answer is clear enough

Comment: The sentence "Having a normal subgroup almost always allows you to express G as a semidirect product of its subgroups" needs some sort of justification! (The "almost always" stops it being obviously false, but it still smells fishy...)

Comment: I think that we are talking elementary group theory here. You obviously have to have other hypotheses, such as $H \unlhd G$, $K < G$, $H \cap K =\{e\}$, and $HK=G$ to talk about semidirect products, but I think that Luca knows that better than I do.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you might be able to establish that your sylow p -subgroup is (or isn't)  normal.  This happens when there is only one, since they are always conjugate.  This can be useful in terms of identifying structure of the parent group, or which group you have up to isomorphism.

For another, depending upon the context,  one can use counting arguments to establish certain outcomes are impossible (like not having any simple groups of a particular order or kind).

Suffice it to say that it turns out to be a very useful tool.

Comment: I'm aware that $n_p$ really bears important information, but my doubt was on the "[...] need not be distinguished [...]" of the popular wiki page that I've linked.

Comment: While they are indeed isomorphic, they are still distinct, because they have different elements. Knowing how many such subgroups is often useful information.

Comment: BTW, groups are isomorphic, not elements.

Comment: Aren't the elements of $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ groups?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your meaning.